# Facebook Graph API - Selecting only posts with a specific field?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to create a feed of Facebook posts pulled from a page, but I only want to include those with a "message" field. I have tried using the following, but this still includes all data/entries.

https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/posts?fields=message&access_token=TOKEN

Any ideas? Is there some kind of WHERE clause that I can use in the URL?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can try FQL on the stream table like -

```
select post_id, source_id, message from stream where source_id = 19292868552 and message != ''
```

Stream FQL table - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/stream